Change monitor settings on Linux Live system but only for a specific system/monitor
I'm about to test different Linux systems on different PCs using their Live Systems, i.e. booting from USB stick. On one PC, the monitor is connected through DVI, and on this system, the screen goes black every second or so, for some seconds, then flashes again.
I found that using the VGA connection on this system and monitor, the display is stable.
Searching the Internet makes me believe, there is a problem with the refresh rate when the monitor is connected via DVI.
Is there a way to change the settings on the Live System USB-Stick when running with VGA, but changing settings for DVI conection?
The symptoms are the same for Linux Mint Cinnamon and for Fedora Workstation (both current system levels).

No, there isn't. Anything you change in a live session won't survive a reboot.
